# pg_restore old database backup

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

Running 9.5 on Ubuntu 16.04
Unsure what database was backed up, I think 8.4

When I run pg_restore I get

```
pg_restore: implied data-only restore
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--


-- Started on 30608-10-13 11:53:01 MDT

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'SQL_ASCII';
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET escape_string_warning = off;
SET row_security = off;

-- Completed on 2018-09-06 11:12:06 MDT

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

When I run `pg_restore -l`

```
;
; Archive created at 30608-10-13 11:53:01 MDT
;     dbname: 
;     TOC Entries: -1835365408
;     Compression: -1
;     Dump Version: 1.11-0
;     Format: CUSTOM
;     Integer: 4 bytes
;     Offset: 8 bytes
;
;
; Selected TOC Entries:
;
```

Obviously there is a timestamp issue, and clearly the TOC entries and compression is off.

Not sure where to go from here. The file size indicates it should be a complete backup. I have multiple backups from same time frame, and they all report similar when I try to restore them.

Is there any way to uncompress the data portion of the file. I can hexedit and see the schema, but the data is in postgres's binary compressed (-Fc) format. I just need to find and verify a few entries, so if there's a manual way to inspect and search, that would work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could extract it just using `-f` parameter:

```
pg_restore -f /path/to/target/file /path/from/source/dump
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html).

Comment: That just outputs the first block into a file rather than standard out...

Comment: It seems your file is corrupted then. The command I showed above will extract entire file not just first block. You could try echoing pg_restore returned code to inspect if it's about a unexpected eof: `echo $?`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the timestamp issue in the output you pasted or I'm missing something.

Though, generally, if you would like to restore only few records, you may want to try `-L` of `pg_restore` in order to to reorder them and restore.

For example,

`pg_restore -l dbdump > dblist`

Edit `dblist` file (By comment them out or leave only those items you want to restore)

`pg_restore -L dblist dbdump`

`pg_restore -d newdb dbdump`

Comment: The second entry in the question is the out put of that. As for the timestamp, the created date of the archive seems suspect.

Comment: Ah, ok. sorry didn't notice that. You might affect from https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/0d9819f7e3be3c4186f0398d007d2fef8809da6a when restore across v8.x to v9.x. Try restore and test on the same version might be helpful, but you might already tried that. Otherwise you have to treat it a corrupted file.